# Print " Read more .. " inside a div after the content exceds fixed height

Tags: javascript, html, css

as the question indicates below is my html code :-

HTML:

```
<div class="compressContent"> //The main div
    <div class="text"> // lets say max width 400px for .text
       <p style="">
          <b style="">
  // content should not exceed after height 400px , but it should display "Read more .. "
          </b>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.compressContent {
    position:                   relative;
    font-family:                sans-serif;
    display:                    block;
    width:                      244px;
    height:                     auto;
    overflow:                   hidden;
}
.compressContent .text {
    color:                      #333;
    padding:                    20px;
    width:                      204px;
    height:                     400px;
    overflow:                   hidden;
    background:                 #E0E0E0;
    font-size:                  .95em;
    line-height:                1;
    text-align:                 justify;
}

.compressContent .text:after {
    content:                    ' ';
    position:                   absolute;
    display:                    block;
    width:                      100%;
    height:                     1em;
    bottom:                     0px;
    left:                       0px;
    background:                 #E0E0E0;
}

.compressContent .text:before {
    content:                    'Read More...';
    text-align:                 right;
    position:                   absolute;
    display:                    block;
    width:                      2em;
    height:                     1em;
    bottom:                     1em;
    right:                      20px;
}
```

But some how this code ain't giving results what are needed. Can someone guide me with the proper syntax? Can it be done using Javascript? some help really appreciated.

Searched on Google & found `text-overflow: ellipsis;` but it depends on a fixed width whereas here it depending on height .

Found a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/microbians/csYjC/) for vertical ellipsis  but not that useful , contains some css error's.

Any solution?

Comment: Its possible doing it with JavaScript yes.. for sure. Have you tried that?

Comment: Here goes a very simple implementation but it should give you an idea on how to do it: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/QbQqOw

Comment: @putvande , Can you guide me with some article or give a psuedo-code that can make me understand what function should be implemented using javascript ? ,

Comment: @zvona  , Thanks for guiding me with that code :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Pure CSS.

The calculation `height: calc(16*20*3);` is `font-size*line-height*-webkit-line-clamp(lines to show)`.

So in this case, 3 lines are being showed. If you want 5 to be shown instead, you change `-webkit-line-clamp: 3;` to `-webkit-line-clamp: 5;` and `height: calc(16*20*3);` to `height: calc(16*20*5);`.

Hope this helps you

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

p {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: calc(16*20*3);
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.</p>
```

Comment: Just a question .... Will this code be affected according to different browser's ?